# How to export mails from thunderbird to geary?

Tags: thunderbird, geary

I'm trying this mail client right now (geary) on openSUSE.
Does anyone know how to export mail local saved mail from thunderbird to geary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geary is an IMAP-only client at the moment, so the only way to import your local mail at the moment is to upload it to an IMAP folder in Thunderbird. Geary will then be able to find it there.

This [feature has been requested](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=767658), but not yet implemented.